# Configure AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance to use 2 subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have 3 AWS Elastic Beanstalk instances which are running Spring microservices. All microservices are making POST requests to each other and using RDS service for database.

Should I isolate database traffic and microservices traffic into separate subnets?
In case it's a good practice is it possible to assign 2 private network IP's for each subnet for every AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot do it using EBS as the instances will auto create and terminate. So you should try to create instances separately and add autoscaling policy on it.

What I usually do is create my EC2 instances in Public subnet and RDS in private subnet and use RDS Security Group and add EC2 instance's Elastic IP, so that all the traffic is going through the EC2 instance and all the traffic coming to EC2 instance is HTTPS coming from ELB.

Adding the below steps as requested:
Ok, So I am assuming you already know a bit about how to create the servers and RDS etc.

1. Create an EC2 instance for each of your microservices.
2. Attach an EIP to each of these instances.
3. Add an Auto-Scaling policy to increase or decrease the instances based on the traffic/CPU Utilization. Make sure you terminate the newest created instance.
4. Add an ELB for this instance and add HTTPS/SSL certificate to secure your traffic.
5. Create RDS in a Private subnet and add instance EIP in RDS SG for 3306 port.

I think you should be able to do this then.

Comment: Can you share the exact steps, please? Looks good solution.

Comment: @PeterPenzov have updated the answer, please check

Comment: @PeterPenzov: Will you award the bounty too?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good practice to directly communicate between instances in EB. The reason is that that [EB instances run in autoscalling group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.as.html). So they can be terminated and replaced at any time by AWS leading to change in their private Ip addresses.

The change in IP will break your application sooner or later. Instances in EB should be accessed using Load Balancer or  private IP.

So if you have some instances that are meant for private access only you could separate them to internal EB environment.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more about `autoscalling group` and the issues that you mention, please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I updated answer with the link to EB and autoscaling. When you write that you have "3 AWS Elastic Beanstalk instances", it means 3 fully separate EB environments? Or a single EB environment with 3 instances?

Comment: Single environment.

Comment: @PeterPenzov So you want to have one microservice on one instance communicating with some differenet microservice on other instance within same EB environment?

Comment: yes - one subnet with communication with DB, second subnet for communication with other microservices.

Comment: @PeterPenzov I think you should reconsider your design. Instances in a single EB environment should be considered as identical, disposable and terminable at any time. They are part of ASG, and should be treated as a group, not individual instances which can run different software.

Comment: @PeterPenzov: Do you want to secure your traffic from EBS to RDS?

Comment: Yes, I want to use SSL and isolate the traffic into separate networks.